# How to generate ".vbp" files from ".frm" files (visual basic project)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

We are new to visual basic project, we got a requirement to recompile vbp project and generate .exe and use it.
In the '.frm' files the version is 'VERSION 5.00', we are just confused which IDE to be used, how to use and how to generate '.vbp' file from ('.frm') it so that we can generate '.exe' file.

We tried to use visual studio with extension .NET framework, we are unclear what to do and how to do and also not sure if visual studio can be used for version 5 frm files.

Need some useful resources or suggestions how to achieve.

Comment: It's not .NET. This isn't VB.NET, it's VB6 if not worse, which was released in 1998. The only IDE that could ever work with VB6 projects was Visual Studio 6. This is essentially a different language, identical to VBA with minor changes

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you even bothering with VB6 files? This would make sense if  you have to migrate VB6 to VB.NET. `Need some useful resources or suggestions how to achieve.` there are very few if any. It's been 20 years. The books and courses are gone, the speakers and authors changed subjects. You may get by with VBA tutorials and courses but these don't cover forms, COM etc. There's no inheritance, no objects, and file access ... the built-in VB commands weren't used even in 1998, people used COM libraries instead

Comment: You have two options, download Microsoft Visual Basic 6, which will be able to open and compile your vbp project. Or option 2: The .frm files are just text files you can open them in notepad to view the actual code, you will then be able to migrate the code to VB.net using VS2022.

Comment: There was a VB6 to .NET migration tool up to Visual Studio 2008 (which you may still be able to obtain if you have a Microsoft subscription).  There may be commercial offerings for upgrading.  Even an automated upgrade will require a lot of fine-tuning to get right, so it may be better to do a ground-up rewrite, especially since that would allow you to take full advantage of the more modern features in newer versions of .NET VB (e.g. generics and Linq for code, WPF for UX).

Comment: I think the "VERSION 5.00" may imply VB5 rather than VB6, but as far as I know there were no backward-incompatible changes in VB6 (only a small number of convenience features added to the VBA language).